# Our house is 140 square meters. How many barrels of paint do you need to buy if you paint yourself?

Tags: walls

Recently, I'm going to decorate the house.
I want to do it myself as much as possible.
How many barrels of paint do you need to buy if you paint yourself?

Comment: This question reminds me of the joke about 2020:  

If 2020 were a math Problem---
A. If you're walking on ice cream at 5 ounces per toaster and your bicycle loses a sock, how much gravy will you need to repaint your hamster?? That pretty much sums up 2020!!
you didn't tell us how much is in a "barrel" in your country....pretty impossible to answer, also is the 140 sq mt the walls? Ceilings, Floors????  You're gunna have to give a lot more detail to get a decent answer.

Comment: you only need about a 1/4 liter to paint yourself ... you could probably give yourself two coats with that amount

Comment: If you're running a high density capsule motel, and you can host about 100 people there, it's going to take a significantly more paint than a single room open-space concept, unless you plan to paint only the ground.

Comment: 5gal ~ $120. Individual gallons are upwards of $40. I just did a single coat on a 25'x60'x12'^ with a 3/4" nap roller and I used about 8gal. We knew it'd be more than 5 so we bought two fives right off the bat and have some left for touch up later. The only reason to not buy a 5 is if it's *really* expensive paint or doesn't come in 5s.

Comment: Measure every surface to be painted, sum and multipy by the number of coats, then double if the surfaces are rough.

Comment: I have not worked with barrels of paint since recommending paint for refinery tanks ( a barrel of zinc rich weigh over 1000 lbs, not easy to move).

Comment: If you will [edit] your question to include the details people have asked for, I'm sure the question will be reopened and you'll get some reasonably decent answers. There are still a lot of variables, though, like the projected coverage rate of the paint you're using, the number of coats you expect to apply, whether the surface has been primed, and if not, what kind of surface you're painting. This will need _lots_ of extra detail, but it can be answered, given those details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 140 square meters refers to the floor area and not wall area, it really says almost nothing about the amount of paint needed. What you need to do is:

- Measure how many square meters of walls (and possibly ceilings) you need to paint.
- Look at paint information (in a store or online) for *coverage* information. This will vary by brand, quality and type of paint. There will also be different numbers for primer vs. regular paint.
- Barrels = ((square meters of wall)/(coverage per liter))/(liters per barrel). Or in US terms ((square feet of wall)/(coverage per gallon))/(gallons per pail).

140 square meters could be one big room - 10 meters x 14 meters = 48 linear meters x 2.5 meters = 120 square meters of walls. Or it could easily be 2 or 3 times as much. Or not so much if a lot of walls are left as natural brick or wood paneling. Too many variables for random people on the internet to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 140 square metres is the part you want to paint, and not merely the floor area.  if not you need to measure how much surface you want to cover with paint.

Then you ask the paint manufacturer for the expected coverage (or spread rate) , something in the ballpark of 8 to 15 square metres per litre, per coat, is common.  different paints will have different coverage rates, and the application methods may have an effect too,  (spray vs roller vs brush, etc)